# Mock UserContext and FacesContext - jUnit

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, jsf-2, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write some basic backingBean tests but I'm stuck with mocking the UserContext and facesContext.

This code is in the code that I'm trying to test:

```
UserContext uc = ContextProvider.getContext();
Locale locale = uc.getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("AppMessages", locale);
String message = bundle.getString("this.is.the.message.key");
```

In another block of code I've got the following:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.getExternalContext().redirect(handleRedirect("someString"));
```

How could I mock these in a standard jUnit test using only mockito? Or do I have to use something like PowerMock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito [can't mock static methods](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limitations_of_Mockito). You have a few options though:

- Extract the code under test to methods which takes the `UserContext` and `ResourceBundle` or `FacesContext` instances as arguments
- Wrap the static method calls in a [factory object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java), and pass the factory objact instance as an argument to the code under test
- PowerMock is an option, but slows down test execution and in my opinion allows bad-practice solutions

Answer (score 0):

Instead create mocks for yourself, you can use [Apache MyFaces Test](http://myfaces.apache.org/test/index.html), which provided already prepared Mock Objects for JSF artifacts. It will work better in a more wide range of cases, with less effort.

Comment: The mocking already happend. If you came faster I could have tried it :). But good to know for the future ofc.